# Unexpected Token in Angulars runtime.js

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I've a strange issue with an Angular frontend that has been running fine for the last months and all of a sudden the page doesn't load anymore (just white).

In the browser console I see the message

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js:1:1)`

Unfortunately I'm not really a web dev and just have limited experience with Angular (rather using React if any). From what I read, this runtime.js is a utility file built by webpack. The whole page runs in a docker container on the server, I tried rebuilding it but issue remains. I see it on every computer in the network and with every browser, so it doesn't seem to be a caching problem.
When I run the Angular project on my local machine with `ng serve` everything works fine, so the application code itself seems to be okay as well.

Is anyone aware of something that has changed recently that could cause such an issue (altough it would have to be the browser...) or could give me a hint in what direction I should dig?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the frontend is trying to fetch data from an endpoint where a json-response is expected. If the endpoint is not accessible for some reason the server then returns a normal html-formatted response, which starts with a ' tag. This '<'-character is not valid json or js and it causes the unexpected token exception.

Maybe on localhost it works fine, because locally you have the necessary permissions to access the endpoint, while on production environment these permissions are lacking?

Comment: The frontend is using gRpc to communicate with the backend, but that has never caused any issue and also when run locally no connection to the backend is needed to get the webpage displayed correctly.